# python: ImportError: cannot import name celery

Tags: python, flask, celery

This might have nothing to do with celery but here is my problem:

I have an app structured like this:

```
/app
   /__init__.py
   /api_1.0/foo.py
/proj
   /__init__.py
   /celery.py
   /tasks.py
```

So in celery.py I create a celery app:

```
flask = create_app(os.getenv('FLASKCONFIG') or None)
celery = Celery(__name__,
    broker=flask.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
    include=['proj.tasks'])

celery.conf.update(flask.config)
```

and in tasks.py there are lists of celery tasks. One of them is `list_users`

In foo.py I try to use the task:

from proj import tasks

but this is causing an importation problem when I do:

```
celery -A proj worker --logleve=info
```

error message:

```
from proj.celery import celery
    ImportError: cannot import name celery
```

Strange enough, if I remove the creation of the flask app and simply create a celery app, the problem goes away.
it looks like a circular import problem. How to avoid this?

Comment: try to put a ```__init__.py``` under proj folder

Comment: @pigletfly already has one but missed in the post. thanks,

Comment: Is there a ```celery``` in your celery.py file?

Comment: @pigletfly Yes there is.